# 3D intersection in R (spatial analysis)

Tags: r, 3d, spatial, intersection

Hi fellow R enthusiasts,

I'm having trouble finding a solution to a geometrical problem in R. I have a raster dataset which represents a terrain with an obstacle (the obstacle is 5 meters).

```
 dat1=list()
 dat1$x=seq(481018,by=10,len=10)
 dat1$y=seq(5628255,by=10,len=10)
 dat1$z=matrix(c(rep(1,40),rep(5,20),rep(1,40)),10,10)
 r=raster(dat1)
 crs(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84"
```

Also I have a spatial line dataframe which intersects **MAYBE** with that obstacle. One point of the line is below (2 m) the obstacle and one above (7 m).

```
x <- c(481060,481060)
y <- c(5628340,5628260)
line <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(cbind(x,y)), ID="a")))
line <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl = line, data = data.frame("p1"=2,"p2"=7),   match.ID = FALSE)
proj4string(line) <-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84")
```

A visualisation can be found here: [3D Intersection of raster and spatial line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZd6w.jpg).

---

How can I find out if and where the line intersects with the obstacle? Is this necessarily a 3D Problem or can it also be also solved in 2D? I searched for quite a while on different solutions but haven't found anything useful yet.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple solution, but certainly not the most efficient one. Assuming the value of the cell in the raster is the height.

```
e<-extract(r,line,cellnumbers=T)[[1]]
```

Gives the height of each cell the lines passes through, along with the cell numbers, that we will need later.

The next step is to calculate the height of the line in those cells. Since you have the beginning and end you can calculate the slope.

```
slope <- (line@data[1,2]-line@data[1,1])/dist(cbind(x,y))
```

Now that we have the slope, we can calculate the height of the line for every cell, based on the distance to the first point.

```
cellcenters <- xyFromCell(r, e[,1], spatial=FALSE) #find the coordinates for the center of the cell
dists <- spDistsN1(cellcenters, c(x[1],y[1]), longlat = FALSE) #calculate the distance to the beginning of the line
height <- dists*slope
```

Now to find intersections, we just have see where the height of the line is smaller or equal than the value extracted from the raster:

```
any(height<=e[,2])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quck responce, but in this solution there is no consideration of the object hight. There might be no intersection with the obstacle if the line is above.

Comment: You are right. I thought 5 was the height but I completely forgot to consider the height of the line. I`m going to edit the question see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for. 
To compare the hights I'm adding the basehight to the line `height <- (dists*slope)+line@data[1,1] `.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to use a polygon instead a line? This would be usefull to check for areal obstacles. e.g. `ext_poly <- as(extent(r), "SpatialPolygons")` The only option I can think of is to have parallel lines to get the correct hight.